# Invalid object name 'dbo.AspNetUsers' showing on when Application is Hosted

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, iis

I am Working on a Multi-tenant ASP.NET MVC Application. 
I have a master Database database the holds information for all tenants, and every Client will then have their Customized database for their personal transactions.

the Master Database has genereted ASP.net Tables for Identity/Login and  a table called tb_CustomerAccount.

in the dbo.ASPNetUsers table, i have added a column called AppUserID which is is foreign key to the tb_CustomerAccount table.

this table has the fields 
AppUserID, 
DatabaseName, 
SQL_Server, 
UserID, 
Password

when a user logs in, the system, will identify the User and lookup for their Database and connect the user to their application interface.

now this works fine on my local machine, but when i Host the App, i get the error "Invalid object name 'dbo.AspNetUsers'".
Trouble shooting the issues, it seems the login is looking at the Demo Tenant Database for Login details and Not the Master Database, and i dont know why that is,

```
private Master_DatabaseEntities db = new Master_DatabaseEntities();
[Authorize]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    string userID;
    string CustomerDatabase;
    long CusID;
    userID = Convert.ToString(User.Identity.GetUserId());
    AspNetUser aspNetUser = db.AspNetUsers.Find(userID);
    CusID = Convert.ToInt64(aspNetUser.CustomerID);
    LogIn_userID = aspNetUser.Id;
    CustomerName = aspNetUser.ussCustomerAccount.Name;
    CustomerDatabase = aspNetUser.ussCustomerAccount.Database;
    ussCustomerAccount ussCustomerAccount = db.ussCustomerAccounts.Find(CusID);
    var db_Connection_Details = new DynamicModel.DataContext(ussCustomerAccount.Server, ussCustomerAccount.Database, ussCustomerAccount.User, ussCustomerAccount.Password);
    return View();
}
```

DbContext:

```
public class DataContext : DbContext
{
    public DataContext(string server, string database, string user, string password)
      : base ("metadata=res://*/Models.DemoCompanyDB.csdl|res://*/Models.DemoCompanyDB.ssdl|res://*/Models.DemoCompanyDB.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string='data source=" + server + ";initial catalog=" + database + ";user id=" + user + ";password=" + password + ";MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework'")
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
    }

    public virtual DbSet<xxx> xxx
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public virtual DbSet<xxx> xxx
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public virtual DbSet<xxx> xxx
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
```

Comment: How are you defining Master_DatabaseEntities

Comment: <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=xxxxx;Initial Catalog=Master_Database;Integrated Security=True;User ID=xxxx; Password=123" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="Master_DatabaseEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.OS_Hub_Model.csdl|res://*/Models.OS_Hub_Model.ssdl|res://*/Models.OS_Hub_Model.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=xxxxxx;initial catalog=DemoCompany;user id=xxxx;password=123;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />

Comment: @TomtemmAzong  `Master_DatabaseEntities` connectionstring, initial catalog should be `Master_Database` instead of `DemoCompany`

Comment: @MohsinMehmood, you are right, it a typing error, initial catalog is Master_Database.

Comment: the Demo_Company Database is access via a Dynamic Connectionstring as indicated in the DbContext code block above

Answer (score 0):

The Issue was with the Master_Database Connection string. 
the Connectionstring was pointing DemoCompany instead of Master_Database as indicated by @MohsinMehmood.

Hope this will help someone with a similar task. 
thanks